# Why is there an "in" in "she'll be in the first woman to hold a top position in the government"?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

I just don't know why there's an *in* in the following sentence:

> If she succeeds, she'll be **in** the first woman to hold a top position in the government.

Taken from [this CNN story](http://edition.cnn.com/interactive/2012/09/world/china.whos.who/).

Why must there be a preposition and does it make any sense? What will be different if the preposition is omitted?

Comment: Where is this quote from? It seems incorrect to put *in* there. It would make more sense for there to be a fullstop after *in*.

Comment: The *in* does not belong there. Nothing belongs there as the sentence is written.

Comment: I suspect it's a printing or typing error on the part of CNN -   unless Liu Yandong intends to do something either rude or disgusting with some high-powered woman, of course! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The use of *in* in that sentence is incorrect. There should be no word where *in* is.

Comment: Thank you all. I'll just assume it's a typing error, but if you google "in the first woman", a number of results where "in" is used this way will show up. Hard to explain.